# Accessing system call arguments

Tags: ebpf, bpf, bcc-bpf

I'm currently writing a system call tracer that stores some information about a system call every time a system call is called. How can I add to this code so that it also stores the system call arguments?

This is the event structure:

```
struct data_t{
u32 pid;
char p_comm[TASK_COMM_LEN];
char comm[TASK_COMM_LEN];
u32 syscall_id;
u64 ts;
};
```

And this is the tracepoint code:

```
TRACEPOINT_PROBE(raw_syscalls,sys_exit){
struct task_struct *task;
u64 pid_tgid = bpf_get_current_pid_tgid();
u32 key = pid_tgid >> 32;
task = (struct task_struct *)bpf_get_current_task();
struct data_t event = {};
bpf_probe_read_kernel_str(&event.p_comm, TASK_COMM_LEN, task->real_parent->comm);
bpf_get_current_comm(&event.comm, sizeof(event.comm));
event.pid = key;
event.syscall_id = args->id;
syscalls.ringbuf_output(&event, sizeof(event),0);
return 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing from the use of the `TRACEPOINT_PROBE` macro that you are using bcc. In that case you can use the `args` variable (declared by the macro) to get to the arguments.

Those arguments are then documented in `/sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/raw_syscalls/sys_exit`:

```
# cat /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/raw_syscalls/sys_exit/format 
name: sys_exit
ID: 347
format:
    field:unsigned short common_type;   offset:0;   size:2; signed:0;
    field:unsigned char common_flags;   offset:2;   size:1; signed:0;
    field:unsigned char common_preempt_count;   offset:3;   size:1; signed:0;
    field:int common_pid;   offset:4;   size:4; signed:1;

    field:long id;  offset:8;   size:8; signed:1;
    field:long ret; offset:16;  size:8; signed:1;

print fmt: "NR %ld = %ld", REC->id, REC->ret
```

So for instance, you could get the `id` argument via `args->id`.